# How to Update asp.NET serverless code at aws lambda to deploy it

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have asp dot net code. and I used command

```
dotnet lambda deploy-serverless
```

But How could I update changes to the already deployed function via above command.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be the same command?

Comment: It again asks for all the information like region, cloud stack name, bucket name etc